# What's the right behavior when overloading operator delete without overloading new? gcc and clang differ

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, operator-overloading, overload-resolution

The following code behaves differently with *clang* (version 5.0.0-3~16.04.1 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) and *gcc* (9.2.0).

```
void operator delete(void* ptr) noexcept {
    std::cout << "overloaded delete" << std::endl;
    free(ptr);
}

int main() {
    int* pint = new int;
    delete pint; // clang doesn't go through overloaded operator delete, gcc does
}
```

***gcc*** goes via the overloaded `operator delete` while ***clang*** avoids it preferring the `global delete`.

(When adding an overloaded `operator new` both compilers agree and go through both overloaded versions).

Code: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0903bd53a8c04a9b

Comment: For info, `MSVC` also goes *via* your overload (`clang-cl` in Visual Studio doesn't).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compilers are allowed to optimize-out allocations with `new` and omit calls to the global replaceable `operator new`s and `operator delete`s completely, even if they have side effects, see [[expr.new]/10](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.new#10) and [[expr.delete]/7.1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.unary#expr.delete-7.1) of the C++17 standard draft.

---

If you compile without the `-O2` flag, you will see your message printed with both compilers and gcc trunk also omits the allocation with optimizations enabled.

---

If the allocation/deallocation function calls are not removed by the compiler, I would assume that your `operator delete` has undefined behavior, because you have no guarantee that the pointer you are being passed was allocated by `malloc` and calling `free` on it has undefined behavior if it wasn't.

You need to always replace both `operator new` and `operator delete`.

Comment: optimization!! how elementary :-) yes when I print the address obtained clang drops the optimization: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5a5ce3408e11db7d

Comment: > You need to always replace both `operator new` and `operator delete`. Is it required by the spec? can you overload only `operator new`?

Comment: @AmirKirsh Skimming through the standard I didn't see anything requiring it directly, but as I mentioned, if you don't replace the `operator new` as well, you don't know how the pointer was allocated and if you don't know how it was allocated, then you don't know how to deallocate it, violating the requirement that a deallocation function deallocate the memory block pointed to by the pointer.